# Java Swing JLayeredPane not showing CardLayout cards & background image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I'm using Java 17 for a little project. I'm doing the Layout with the AWT `CardLayout` and the graphical components with Swing.

I want to change my currently active `JPanel` in `Window.java` whenever I click on one of the `JMenuBarItem`s inside my `Navbar.java` class but show my background image from my `BackgroundImage` class all the time by using a `JLayeredPane`.

Window.java:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
JPanel cards;
JLayeredPane layeredPane;

JPanel openPokédex = new OpenPokédexPanel();

public Window() {
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    }
});

this.setSize(800, 600);

layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
this.setContentPane(layeredPane);

BackgroundImage background = new BackgroundImage();
layeredPane.add(background, Integer.valueOf(0));

cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
layeredPane.add(cards, Integer.valueOf(1));

cards.add(openPokédex, "openPokedex");

Navbar bar = new Navbar(cards, this);
this.setJMenuBar(bar);

this.setVisible(true);
}

public void switchPanel(String panelName) {
    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
    cardLayout.show(cards, panelName);
    System.out.println(panelName);
}
}
```

Navbar.java:

```
public class Navbar extends JMenuBar{
JPanel cards;
Window window;

public Navbar(JPanel cards, Window window) {
this.cards = cards;
this.window = window;

JMenu pokedex = new JMenu("Pokédex");
JMenuItem openPokedex = new JMenuItem("Open");
pokedex.add(openPokedex);

this.add(pokedex);

// Events
openPokedex.addActionListener(e -> window.switchPanel("openPokedex"));
}
}
```

OpenPokédexPanel.java:

```
public class OpenPokédexPanel extends JPanel {

OpenPokédexPanel() {
// tried doing transparent background but made no difference
//this.setOpaque(false);
//this.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));

// pretty much irrelevant. just to see if the panel is actually there
JButton pokémonButton = new JButton("Pokémon");
this.add(pokémonButton);
}
}
```

BackgroundImage.java:

```
public class BackgroundImage extends JComponent {
BufferedImage image = null;

public BackgroundImage() {
File bgimage = null;

File directory = new File("src/bin/");

if (directory.isDirectory()) {
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    
    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
    Random rng = new Random();
    File randomFile = files[rng.nextInt(files.length)];
    bgimage = randomFile;
    
    } else {
    System.out.println("No images!");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a directory!");
}

try {
    image = ImageIO.read(bgimage);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
if (image != null) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
}
}
```

Before trying to combine the `BackgroudImage` with the `CardLayout`, the background image worked fine but the `JPanel`s weren't showing up because they apparently spawned behind my background image. I want to have a permanent background with `JPanel` displaying content on top.
At the moment it only shows a white screen when starting the program

**EDIT 1**

I modified `OpenPokédexPanel` JPanel class:

```
public class OpenPokédexPanel extends JPanel {

OpenPokédexPanel() {

this.setOpaque(false); // added this again
//this.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));

JButton pokémonButton = new JButton("Pokémon");
this.add(pokémonButton);
}
}
```

and I modified the main `Window` class. I removed the `JLayeredPane` and added the following code as @camickr suggested:

```
BackgroundImage background = new BackgroundImage();
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.setContentPane(background);

cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.setOpaque(false);
background.add(cards);

cards.add(openPokédex, "openPokedex");
```

The background image shows up but the `JPanel` card `openPokédex` won't show up as well on click.

Comment: `JLayeredPane` doesn't have a layout manager applied by default, so none of the components will be give any kind of sizing (default `0x0`); `File directory = new File("src/bin/");` <- Don't reference `src` in your code, it won't exist once you export the project.

Comment: @MadProgrammer when trying to apply a layout manager by doing e.g. `layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` I get an error saying `cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)` which references the second parameter of `layeredPane.add(background, Integer.valueOf(0));`. can you pls explain what you mean by the `src` not existing once i export the project?

Comment: No need to use a JLayeredPane. Just use your BackgroundImage component as the content pane (with a BorderLayout) and add your panel with the CardLayout to the content pane. Of course an component you add to the content pane must use `setOpaque(false)` so you can see the background image. Also the panels you add to the CardLayout must be non-opaque.

Comment: @camickr could you please show me how you would apply your solution in an answer? i tried applying what you wrote which made the background image show up but the JPanel cards are still not showing up. the JPanels still seem to be behind each other

Comment: @fullstacknoob Yes, then you'd need to use `JLayeredPane#setLayer` instead

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with random lines of code posted. The issue may be in code not provided. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test. That is why I suggested first getting the code to work without the image, just the background color so we can see if all the panels are added/displayed properly. Also note the "navbar" is not required for an MRE. The point of the MRE is to simplify the problem and get that working. Then you add more logic instead of trying to write all the logic at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `JLayeredPane` this way, then you will need to apply a suitable layout manager to it, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Navigatable {
        enum View {
            MENU, CONTENT;
        }
        public void show(View view);
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel implements Navigatable {

        private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        private MenuPane menuPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            add(layeredPane);

            layeredPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            BackgroundPane backgroundPane = new BackgroundPane();
            layeredPane.add(backgroundPane, gbc);
            layeredPane.setLayer(backgroundPane, Integer.valueOf(0));

            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            contentPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);
            contentPane.setOpaque(false);

            layeredPane.add(contentPane, gbc);
            layeredPane.setLayer(contentPane, Integer.valueOf(1));

            contentPane.add(new MenuPane(this), Navigatable.View.MENU.name());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is the content");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            contentPane.add(label, Navigatable.View.CONTENT.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void show(View view) {
            cardLayout.show(contentPane, view.name());
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {
        public MenuPane(Navigatable navigatable) {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Show me the content");
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    navigatable.show(Navigatable.View.CONTENT);
                }
            });
        }       
    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage bgImage;

        public BackgroundPane() {
            try {
                bgImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Mando01-50.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (bgImage != null) {
                return new Dimension(bgImage.getWidth(), bgImage.getHeight());
            }
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (bgImage == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = (getWidth() - bgImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - bgImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(bgImage, x, y, this);
        }
    }
}
```

But, a generally better solution would probably be to make use of the background pane directly, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Navigatable {
        enum View {
            MENU, CONTENT;
        }
        public void show(View view);
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel implements Navigatable {

        private BackgroundPane backgroundPane;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        private MenuPane menuPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            backgroundPane = new BackgroundPane();
            backgroundPane.setLayout(cardLayout);
            add(backgroundPane);

            backgroundPane.add(new MenuPane(this), Navigatable.View.MENU.name());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is the content");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            backgroundPane.add(label, Navigatable.View.CONTENT.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void show(View view) {
            cardLayout.show(backgroundPane, view.name());
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {
        public MenuPane(Navigatable navigatable) {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Show me the content");
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    navigatable.show(Navigatable.View.CONTENT);
                }
            });
        }       
    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage bgImage;

        public BackgroundPane() {
            try {
                bgImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Mando01-50.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (bgImage != null) {
                return new Dimension(bgImage.getWidth(), bgImage.getHeight());
            }
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (bgImage == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x = (getWidth() - bgImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - bgImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(bgImage, x, y, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i applied your second approach and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Swing has a parent/child relationship. You would have a structure like:

- frame

  - BackgroundImage (using BorderLayout) as the content pane

    - non opaque panel (using CardLayout)

      - non opaque panel
      - non opaque panel

Basic solution is:

```
JPanel background = new BackgroundImage();
background.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
frame.setContentPane( background );

JPanel cards = new JPanel( new CardLayout() );
cards.setOpaque( false );
background.add( cards );

JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
card1.add( new JLabel("Label for first card") );
card1.setOpaque( false );
cards.add(card1, "card1");

JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
card2.add( new JLabel("Label for second card") );
card2.setOpaque( false );
cards.add(card2, "card2");
```

So first get the above code working so you see the background color of your panel and one of the cards displaying. If you have problems then you can post your code showing exactly what you have done. Once that works, then you replace the basic components with your custom components. If it stops working you know what you just changed.

Comment: i edited my question and showed how I applied your solution. the problem unfortunately still persists